# ng-repeat going out of div

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a ng-repeat

```
 <div class="description-block" style="text-align: left; margin: 0px">
       <span class="description-text">Targets:   </span>
       <span ng-repeat="target in obj.targets" class="label label-danger">{{target}}</span>
 </div><!-- /.description-block -->
```

But the elements are going out from div

Here it is:
[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: That is something you need to fix with the css

Comment: As Sajeetharan has said this issue is not with `ng-repeat` but with css. Edit the question and put the definitions of your css classes.

Comment: the css is only about text style.

Answer (score 1):

it's something to do with css, how about add `display: block;` or `display: inline-block;` on your div style. If it's still overflow then set width to your div.

example:

```
 <div class="description-block" style="text-align: left; margin: 0px; display: block;">
   // your spans
</div>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Still the same problem :/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="description-block" style="text-align: left; margin: 0px; overflow-y:scroll">
   <span class="description-text">Targets:   </span>
   <span ng-repeat="target in obj.targets" class="label label-danger">{{target}}</span>
```

fix the width of the div and add css property, overflow-y: scroll. that will work fine. and if you do not work scroll bar just set the max-width of div and the content will be in next line.

Comment: Actually I don't want scroll, just write in the next line